# Change image based on date/time with JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am using the below code to switch between 2 class names on a page element based on what time of the day it is. Currently the class name will switch between the hours of 07:00AM - 23:00PM.

Is it possible to alter this code so that we could have one timeframe for days Monday - Friday and another timeframe for Saturday and Sunday?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
window.setInterval(SetImage,0);   /* set this to at least 10 min */

function SetImage(){
    var nowdate = new Date();
    var waketime = new Date();
    waketime.setHours(7);
    waketime.setMinutes(00);

    var bedtime = new Date();
    bedtime.setHours(23);
    bedtime.setMinutes(00);

    if(waketime < nowdate  && nowdate < bedtime) {
         document.body.setAttribute('data-daytime','');
    }else{
         document.body.setAttribute('data-nighttime','');
    }
}
});
```

Comment: yes. Just get the day and then change your logic accordingly. const day = new Date().getDay(). 1 = monday, 7 = sunday and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can take a look at `getDay()` to get what day it is.

you can do something like this

```
const defaultSchedule = { wake: 7, bed: 23 }
const schedule = {
  // Sunday - Saturday : 0 - 6
  0: { wake: 9, bed: 23 },
  6: { wake: 9, bed: 03 },
}
const times = schedule[new Date().getDay()] || defaultSchedule
waketime.setHours(times.wake);
bedtime.setHours(times.bed);
```